# How can I display the first n different lines in two files from a shell?

Tags: text-processing, command-line

How can I display the first n different lines in two files from a shell ? I've tried with `grep -vf` but it does not really work.

Suppose n = 5
This input:

`file1`

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
n
o
```

`file2`

```
This line is not the same
b
c
d
This is still not the same
Neither is this
g
h
Nor this
DIFFERENT
k
This is not the same, too
m
another different line
o
```

Would produce the output:

```
This line is not the same
This is still not the same
Neither is this
Nor this
DIFFERENT
```

Comment: "first n different lines" suggests using "diff" to find the differences, So maybe 

`diff file1 file2 | grep '^[<>]' | head -6`

is what you want? We can replace grep by sed if you don't want an indication of which file this cam from.

Comment: Thank you for your response! What does the ‘^[<>]’ actually do? And would the sed version look exactly the same exact for replacing ‘grep’ with ‘sed’ ?

Comment: It is simplest if you actually look at the output of `diff file1 file2`, as I can't put formatted output in a comment. Essentially each line of output is either a range of lines to apply to or a copy of one of the input lines with `< ` or `> ` added at the start. The grep is to remove the range of lines lines. Using sed I would say `sed -n 's/^[<>] //'` (and maybe even put in some quit logic.) My solution would show both `a` and `This line is not the same` because both are different. If you change `[<>]` to `[>]` you get closer to your desired output.

Comment: Thank you so much! I’ve run the code you provided in the meantime and tried some things and you sir really helped me!

Comment: If you don't want/need to handle the possibility of lines being added/removed, so you can just read one line from each file, compare them, discard them if they are the same else print 1, then this can be coded as a simple loop in bash. I can write this as an answer if this simpler problem is what you need.

Comment: Your previous answer suffices in my case, but maybe you could help someone else reading this question in the future, so why not? Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

This is my proposal:

```
diff -u file1 file2 --unchanged-line-format= --old-line-format= --new-line-format=%L | head -n 5

This line is not the same
This is still not the same
Neither is this
Nor this
DIFFERENT
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your files don't contain the TAB character (if they do, choose another unambiguous delimiter) you could do

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk -F'\t' '$2 != $1 {print $2; n++} n==5 {exit}'
This line is not the same
This is still not the same
Neither is this
Nor this
DIFFERENT
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bash primitives, using fixed file descriptors to keep things simple.
(Untested)

```
# open the two files on fd8 and fd9, should have some error checking
exec 8<file1 9<file2
# start the loop
for(c=0;c<6;)
do
    # read a line from first file, don't worry about EOF 
    IFS="" read -r -u 8 l1
    # read a line from second file, exit the loop if EOF
    read -r -u 9 l2 || break
    # loop if the 2 lines are the same
    [ "$l1" -eq "$l2" ] && continue
    # ok, a different line. Output from file2, bump count and loop
    let c++
    printf '%s\n' "$l2"
done
# If we get here we either have hit EOF on file2 or have printed our 6 lines
# Either way just tidy up
# close the file descriptiors
exec 8<&- 9<&-
```